# jQuery build html add loop

Tags: jquery

Hi what i have is this.

```
var items = new Array('1','2','3','4','5');
var img = $('<div>',{'id':'slider'});
$.each(items,function(index,src){     
    var li = $('<img>',{src});        
    img.append(li);      
    });
$('body').append(img);
```

Which create.

```
<div id="slider">
  <img src="1">
  <img src="2">
  <img src="3">
  <img src="4">
  <img src="5">
</div>
```

What i am struggling with is to add a tag "figure" and "alt".
So it should look like this.

```
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="1" alt="">
    <img src="2" alt="">
    <img src="3" alt="">
    <img src="4" alt="">
    <img src="5" alt="">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set attribute on elements.

```
var items = new Array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
var img = $('<div>', {
    'id': 'slider'
});
$.each(items, function (index, src) {
    var li = $('<img />').attr({
        src: 'SRCHERE',
        alt: 'TEXT'
        // ^^^^^^^^
    });

    img.append(li);
});
$('body').append(img);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vcaawLr2/)

Comment: @JeremyC. That's what the `jQuery` does

Comment: Nice,but you are missing "figure" tag.No problem i have got answer under.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 var div = $('<div>',{'id':'slider'});
 var figure=$('<figure>');
 $.each(items,function(index,src){     
  var li = $('<img>', {
  src: src,
  alt: 'test'
 });        
 figure.append(li);      
});
$('body').append(div.append(figure));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/djw3387c/)**

Answer (score 0):

why don't try try this

```
var items = new Array('1','2','3','4','5');
var img = $('<div>',{'id':'slider'});
var figure = $('<figure>');
$.each(items,function(index,src){     
    var li = $('<img>',{src});
    li.attr('alt', '');        
    figure.append(li);      
    });
img.append(figure);
$('body').append(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
var items = new Array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
var img = $('<div>', {
    'id': 'slider'
});
var $fig = $('<figure />').appendTo(img)
$.each(items, function (index, src) {
    var li = $('<img>', {
        src,
        alt: ''
    });
    $fig.append(li);
});
$('body').append(img);
```